# How do global consts that are not copy or clone work in Rust?

Tags: rust, constants, move

Say I have the following snippet ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb5aed8b9018452171d41bf6ba7e469c))

```rust
struct A {
    pub val: u32
}

const GLOBAL_A: A = A {val: 2};

fn main() {
    let some_a: A = GLOBAL_A;
    let other_a: A = GLOBAL_A;

    println!("double val = {}", some_a.val + other_a.val);
}
```

Since `A` is neither `Clone` nor `Copy`, I would assume the value of `GLOBAL_A` would be moved. That does not make much sense for a const and as shown cannot be the case anyways since it can be "moved" twice.

What are the rules that allow the above snippet to work considering `A` is not `Clone` nor `Copy`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Constants are always inlined. Your example is essentially the same as

```rust
struct A {
    pub val: u32
}

fn main() {
    let some_a: A = A {val: 2};
    let other_a: A = A {val: 2};

    println!("double val = {}", some_a.val + other_a.val);
}
```

The value is reconstructed twice, so it doesn't need to be `Copy` or `Clone`.

On the other hand, `static`s are not inlined:

```rust
struct A {
    pub val: u32
}

static GLOBAL_A: A = A {val: 2};

fn main() {
    let some_a: A = GLOBAL_A;
}
```

results in

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of static item `GLOBAL_A`
 --> src/main.rs:8:21
  |
8 |     let some_a: A = GLOBAL_A;
  |                     ^^^^^^^^
  |                     |
  |                     move occurs because `GLOBAL_A` has type `A`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                     help: consider borrowing here: `&GLOBAL_A`
```